# where and how these parameters in laravel are set? `LARAVEL_LOAD_HOST` , `LARAVEL_LOAD_PORT` , `LARAVEL_LOAD_USER`?

Tags: php, environment-variables, laravel-8

After trying to use `php artisan schema:dump`, I got this error.

```
The command "mysqldump   --skip-add-drop-table --skip-add-locks --skip-comments --skip-set-charset --tz-utc --host="${:LARAVEL_LOAD_HOST}" --port="${:LARAVEL_LOAD_PORT}" --user="${:LARAVEL_LOAD_USER}" --password="${:LARAVEL_LOAD_PASSWORD}" "${:LARAVEL_LOAD_DATABASE}" --routines --result-file="${:LARAVEL_LOAD_PATH}" --no-data" failed.
```

BTW the main question is not how to solve this problem. but my question is where does these parameters defined? (`LARAVEL_LOAD_HOST`, `LARAVEL_LOAD_PORT`, `LARAVEL_LOAD_USER`, `LARAVEL_LOAD_PASSWORD`, etc.)
why laravel does not use `env` constants for equivalent value of these parameters? who set these parameters and when this setting is done?

Thanks for any hint,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick look under the hood reveals that those keys are set in `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlSchemaState.php` (or `SqliteSchemaState.php` or `PostgressSchemaState.php` - depends on what you're using).

```
/**
 * Get the base variables for a dump / load command.
 *
 * @param  array  $config
 * @return array
 */
protected function baseVariables(array $config)
{
    $config['host'] = $config['host'] ?? '';

    return [
        'LARAVEL_LOAD_SOCKET' => $config['unix_socket'] ?? '',
        'LARAVEL_LOAD_HOST' => is_array($config['host']) ? $config['host'][0] : $config['host'],
        'LARAVEL_LOAD_PORT' => $config['port'] ?? '',
        'LARAVEL_LOAD_USER' => $config['username'],
        'LARAVEL_LOAD_PASSWORD' => $config['password'],
        'LARAVEL_LOAD_DATABASE' => $config['database'],
    ];
}
```

`$config` array provided to the `baseVariables` methods contains the values from `config/database.php` (for your connection).